# Synced user cannot be found - EnsureUser - AD - SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user, ad

I've created 1500 mysites (pre-provisioning), but there are 25 user that don't get their mysites.

All users can be found after running a sync, but when I try to check for a user with powershell I get:

> Exception calling "EnsureUser" with "1" argument(s): "The specified user i:0#.w|awesome\superawesome could not be found."

```
$site = get-spsite https://awesome.no
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$user = $web.EnsureUser(“i:0#.w|awesome\superawesome”)
$user.Sid
```

I've tried to find the users using people picker and it works in central admin and in the web application.

I've also tried to check permission on the root page, and I also found the specific user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reconfigured the peoplepicker and it worked like a charm.

```
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this workaround worked for me:

```
$loginName = "awesome\service_running_sync"

$password = "password123"

$domain = "awesome.no"

$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://awesome.no

$adSearchObj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain

$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$adSearchObj.DomainName = $domain

$adSearchObj.IsForest = $false #$true for Forest, $false for Domain 

$adSearchObj.LoginName = $loginName

$adSearchObj.SetPassword( $userPassword )

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)

$adSearchObj = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain

$adSearchObj.DomainName = "local.domain.sync"

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)

$wa.Update(*)
```

**A possible root cause could be to be this:**

When you execute a People Picker query, that makes a NetBIOS call to try to resolve the domain name. Because the WINS is not set up, a NetBIOS broadcast occurs. However, the broadcast cannot find the trusted domains because broadcasts are not enabled outside the subnet.